# What is the use of wild card masks vs normal masks

Tags: ipv4

I've always wondered what the use of wild card masks was. When I learned about them in college  I wondered what the use was, we saw that you could separate subnets by for instance even and uneven IPs. What is the practical use of wild card masks vs normal subnet masks?

Comment: So basically the wild card mask bypasses the uses of a subnet mask because its easier is binary to calculate because of reverse binary.

Comment: Little mistyping there. But binary speaking its use is easier then a standard subnet mask?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand it, the question is what is the reason for the two different masks, not what are the differences between the masks. The two questions overlap somewhat, but it comes down to binary math (as YLearn hits on).

First, a netmask:

```
IP:   1100 0000 . 1010 1000 . 1111 1000 . 0110 0100 = 192.168.248.100
Mask: 1111 1111 . 1111 1111 . 1111 1111 . 1111 1000 = 255.255.255.248
AND:  1100 0000 . 1010 1000 . 1111 1000 . 0110 0000 = 192.168.248.96
```

The **AND** operation on the IP address with the netmask results in the network `192.168.248.96/29`.

Next, a wildcard:

```
NET:  1100 0000 . 1010 1000 . 1111 1000 . 0110 0000 = 192.168.248.96
WC:   0000 0000 . 0000 0000 . 0000 0000 . 0000 0111 = 0.0.0.7
OR:   1100 0000 . 1010 1000 . 1111 1000 . 0110 0111 = 192.168.248.103
```

performing an OR operation on the network results in the range of IPs (192.168.248.96-103) that may be permitted or blocked in an ACL or OSPF network statement (remember that OSPF only looks for interfaces that fall within the specified ranges -- i.e. it doesn't match IP *and* netmask, just the IP). It's very easy to check whether an IP is in range with:

> IP **OR** WC == NET **OR** WC

This is useful to the router because the netmask does not easily give you this information (without additional operations).

Answer (score 12):

There are some odd corner cases you can do with wild card masks that are difficult to do with subnet masks - for example, you could do 1.2.*.4 easily in a wild card mask that would be hard to do in a subnet mask.  How practical this is is left up to the operator in question.

Basically a wild card mask splits up each bit into a 'match' or 'don't care' setting.  if you have 255.255.255.33. for example, that would translate to '11111111.11111111.11111111.00100001'.  If the original IP was 1.1.1.200, this translates to 00000001.00000001.00000001.10001000.  Using the example given, which is starting to make my brain hurt from doing binary math, only the 3 and 8th bit of the last octet would have to match the original IP in order to be a pass (along with the other 3 octets).

Comment: Indeed that's what I was wondering about what the practical uses are

Comment: 255.255.0.255 - pretty simple if you ask me

Comment: That's not a valid subnet mask.

Comment: it's perfectly valid, it's just not valid for the purposes of configuring an address in a CIDR-based environment. On a firewall or other system that doesn't care about it being a longest-prefix compliant mask, it's completely valid. iptables or an access-list are a good example.

Computers aren't magic, 1.2.x.4 is identical to 255.255.0.255 in terms of bitmasking, it's the difference between a regex and a logical AND.

Comment: "not valid for the purposes of configuring an address in a CIDR-based environment" - is that not a subnet mask?

Comment: Don't try to play semantics with me, "subnet mask" and "wildcard mask" are equally misnomers. Nowhere did I use the word "subnet mask" in my statement. a mask is a mask, what matters is its purpose.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm understanding more what's going on - Aaron had said "1.2.*.4 would be hard to do in a subnet mask", which it would. Your response of "255.255.0.255" is **the wildcard mask** that would match Aaron's example, but he is still correct in stating that matching that **with a subnet mask** would be difficult to do (if not impossible). I was assuming your response was in "subnet mask" form, rather than "wildcard mask" form (and you also jumped the gun in dismissing his original statement without reading it fully IMO).

Answer (score 5):

Wildcard masks are also used to specify source/destination subnets (or specific addresses) in access control lists. They're also used to specify protocol interfaces that OSPF will use in more "traditional" versions of IOS (NX-OS and probably IOS-XR notwithstanding).

edit: A subnet mask's job is to separate host bits from network bits. The number of 1's in the subnet mask **has to be contiguous**.

```
11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000 <-- valid subnet mask (/16)
11111111.11111111.11111000.00000000 <-- valid subnet mask (/21)
11111111.11111111.00111000.00000000 <-- whoops, invalid subnet mask
```

Wildcard masks are not bound by this rule (hence the term "wildcard"), therefore you can do things like Aaron had mentioned, ie:

```
access-list 1 permit 192.168.200.0 0.6.0.8
```

This will permit:

```
192.168.200.0
192.172.200.0
192.168.200.8
192.172.200.8
```

Comment: Alright but why can't regular subnets not address this?

Comment: A subnet mask does nothing more than to separate host bits from network bits. It **must be** contiguous. You do not have this restriction with wildcard masks - hence the term "wildcard." This makes them better suited for more arbitrary host or network specification.

Comment: @JohnJensen nice description of the "wildcard". Makes me remember it better :) You should put this in the original answer!

Comment: I've amended my answer to include this - not sure if you meant mine or Aaron's though.

Comment: @JohnJensen I meant yours :) (just like you edited)

Answer (score 2):

They are somewhat a hold out from when bits were precious and processing data in certain ways (binary AND or binary OR) was less taxing.

Today, they are still useful in other cases, as Aaron has already mentioned.